# Using Cron Job to run a python programs

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a python program using cron.
Initially I tried running a web scraper in python using cron, but I quickly realized that something was wrong.
So I tried breaking down the process to see where the error was.
And I found out that cron actually won't run any python program that is more complicated than a
`print("Hello World")`

For starters I'm trying to run this code using cron:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

sys.stdout = open("/home/pi/testbot/crontask.txt", "w")

df = pd.read_excel('db.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(df)

sys.stdout.close()
```

I want the program to read a .xlsx file and write the output into a file called crontask.txt.

**Now here comes the twist.**

When I run the command `python3 testbot.py`
I get the right result, and content in the crontask.txt.

But when I add `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/testbot/testbot.py >> /home/pi/testbot/log.txt` to crontab, I get zero results and zero log-entries in log.txt.

I've tried to make the .py file exeutable with `chmod +x testbot.py` and change permissions without luck.

I'm starting to wonder if the only way to run such programs is to make a script that runs the program and use cron job on that.
Is that my only solution?

Comment: From what you wrote, I clearly see a typo: there is a space in your `testbot.py` file path.

Comment: Also, you can/should look in your system logs `/var/log/<somewhere-here-around>.log` to see if cron is complaining about something.

Comment: @Brandt, Yeah, that was just a typo here, I had to check twice. 
Thanks for the notice tho!

Comment: And, as a best practices note, I advise you to have cron calling a very simple shell script, without arguments from a "cron_scripts" folder in your home. That script would call your python script and do whatever environment/log setup necessary. You can have many advantages of this aproach: first, it makes your crontab clean and simple, second, apart from any env/setup you can use it (e.g. "call_textbot.sh") to document the job ;)

Comment: Last but not least, understand the phylosophy of *nix commands (to do one thing properly done) helps you understand such "best practices": don't put the burden of complex calls onto cron's back, it is meant to call a script periodically. Period. And it _does do_ that amazingly well.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this one, and as embarrassing as the fault was I still want to post this in case someone else experience the same problem.

As cron doesn't use any spesific paths you have to specify everything in order for it to execute programs that opens any folder/file or other program.
Not just in crontab but also in the programs themself.
In my case it was the `df = pd.read_excel('db.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')` that caused the error, so when I changed it to `df = pd.read_excel('/home/pi/bot/db.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')` it worked like a charm.

The same thing goes if you consider using a bash script to open another program. Only direct paths seem to work.